# php array how to dynamically insert data into mysql table when field names not known in advance?

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, insert

I receive some data in an array, that will be stored in a mysql table. The table field names are the same as the `key` in the key/value pair in the array, however I do not know in advance which key/value pairs will arrive

```
// First execution
$array1 = array('a'=> 'str1', 'b'=> 'str2', 'c'=> 'str3', 'd'=> 'str4');

// second execution
$array2 = array('a'=> 'str6', 'c'=> 'str7', 'e'=> 'str5');

// third execution
$array3 = array('b'=> 'str8', 'd'=> 'str9', 'e'=> 'str10');
```

So the above indicates the way in which the data can arrive. Below is the example of db table structure

```
column 1 name = id (auto increment)
column 2 name = 'a'
column 3 name = 'b'
column 4 name = 'c'
column 5 name = 'd'
column 6 name = 'e'
column 7 name = 'f'
```

Note that there may be some unexpected data, but if a db field (column) does not exist for that unexpected value then the data should be skipped. I basically just need to insert the data where a column exists for it and any non existant values should be null for the column. I hope this makes sense to someone.

How do I construct the SQL in php?

Comment: In theory you could DESCRIBE TABLE before doing any inserts, but I'd really really advise against that, as you're really going to hurt performance if you're going to be interacting with a lot of tables.  You're probably better off implementing a set of classes that know how the underlying tables are laid out

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the list of column names from the array keys, and the list of values from the array values. Something like:

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);
$vals = array();
foreach ($keys as $k)
{
    $vals[] = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($arr[$k])."'";
}
$qry = "INSERT into tab1 (".implode(',', $keys).") VALUES (".implode(',', $vals).")";
```

You still need to find a way to remove keys that are not in the table though. I think GordonM's idea of using DESCRIBE TABLES is probably the way to go, then filter $keys (once you've got the list of column names, use array_intersect())

Answer (score 0):

You can use Zend_Db_Table that is part of the Zend Framework. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html
Note that you can use it as a library, you don't need to use the framework. Zend_Db_Table has a method for retrieving the table metadata so it is very easy filter the array. It also provides functionality to cache the metadata.

A simple example:

```
$db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array(
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'test',
    'password' => 'test',
    'dbname'   => 'test'
));
Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($db);
$table = new Zend_Db_Table('table_name');    
$info = $table->info();

// assuming array1 contains keys => values    
$arr = array_intersect_key($array1,array_flip($info['cols']));    
$table->insert($arr);
```